# MySQL insert multiple values when I have foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have stuck many hours and i'd like your help.

I have two arrays:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists chr(
id_chr int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
number int(10),
genename varchar(30) not null,
ensembleid varchar(30) not null,
strand int(10) not null,
band varchar(10) not null, 
genestart int(30) not null,
geneend int(30) not null,
biotype varchar(30),
status varchar(10),
transcriptsnum int(10),
gc float(10) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(id_chr)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists gene(
id_gene int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(30) not null,
transcriptid int(30) not null,
idchr int(10) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(id_gene)
);
```

So far I have inserted values to chr table (8000 lines approximately) and I want a multiple insert for table gene as well.

I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

The question is, how can I insert the values for the `foreign key` due to the fact I have to insert multiple rows?

Comment: Where is a foreign key for gene table in the above create table definition?

Comment: Your two tables have different columns that likely mean the same thing: `transcriptsnum` and `transcriptid` (less likely considering the `gene` table's `transcriptid` is `int(30)`, but I am thinking that's a copy/paste error), and `idchr` against `id_chr`. I assume `transcriptsnum` and its sibling are foreign keys to another table, and `idchr` is the real problem. In order to associate a `gene` with a `chr`omosome, you must first insert the chromosome. I don't really see what's preventing that from the post though, unless that's just the question you needed answered.

Comment: Can you give a small example of how you are actually doing the `INSERT`s?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

INSERT INTO gene(name,transcriptid,idchr)
select value1,value2,id_chr from char
```

Comment: chr: PK id_chr and for gene: PK:id_gene  FK:idchr

Comment: ok then you can use this to insert multiple id_char values in gene

Comment: @user1681361 what do you mean with multiple insert, can you please post some of the code that it didn't work for you. just to know where you are at and what's missing from your code.

Comment: for example, in teh table with the foreign key the first 5 rows have the same value for the foreign_key, the next 10 the same etc. but i want to inser 3000 records. how can i do that ?

Comment: You keep saying there's a foreign key, but there isn't one in the CREATE TABLE commands you posted above.

Comment: you can do this with the query i have mentioned above

Comment: just replace the select query above with your actual select query

Comment: $sql= "INSERT INTO gene (name,transcriptid)
VALUES ('ENSG00000185055','ENST00000469099'),
('ENSG00000185055','ENST00000480514'),
('ENSG00000185055','ENST00000485614'), etc.. ";

Comment: but i cannot make this because i have problem with the foreign key of gene table. i don't know how to give values on this

Comment: why are you not using idchar column in your insert statement

Comment: "INSERT INTO gene (name,transcriptid,id_chr) SELECT 'ENSG00000185055','ENST00000485614',id_chr from parenttable where id_chr=''

Comment: ok thank you very much.. could you please tell me how can i handle the fact that i have to make 3000 inserts like the above ???

Comment: and also i didn't understand what you said :  from parenttable where id_chr=''?? you say id_chr has no value?

Comment: man if you knw which id_chr to insert then there is no problem else you have to get that value from parenttable.if you knw which id_char value to insert then just populate 3000 insert statements for one time insert

Comment: I have clearly asked you whether you knw the values of id_chr to be inserted or need to fetch from parenttable?

Comment: ok maybe i have to be more specific. i need to insert values in a table (which contains a FK) in which the first 20 have the same FK value, the next 30 the same, blah blah blah.. but i can not do this by hand as the inserts are about 3000. which is the best way to do it ??

Comment: for all these 3000 you have the same FK value?

Comment: i know id_chr is PK to chr table and i want this to be transfered to gene table with what i mentioned above!

Comment: and other 2 column values you are hardcoding rite?

Comment: then remaining 2990. i don't know what you mean. from the 3000 inserts some of them have same FK. the other NO!

Comment: how do u get these values of fk?

Comment: The original data has to come from somewhere. Where is it?